# Convert NCalc expression to string

Tags: c#, ncalc

I'm have to calculate string input using NCalc, but I would like to save it (result) as a string. How do I do that?

```
Expression expressionEv = new Expression(expressionProccessed);
string value = expressionEv.Evaluate ();
```

Following code returns error:

```
Error CS0266: Cannot implicitly convert type `object' to `string'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
```

Is there any way to convert it to string? Or maybe other way? Thanks in advance! ;)

Comment: have you tried `.ToString()` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error message tells you almost everything you need to know:

```
Error CS0266: Cannot implicitly convert type `object' to `string'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
```

Lets look at this in parts.

1.

```
`Cannot implicitly convert type `object' to `string'.`
```

This part is telling you that the call to expressionEv.Evaluate(); is returning a something that has the type 'object', not string.  You cannot assign types to other types.

2.

```
An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
```

This part is telling you that you are attempting to convert the object to a string, and while it is possible, you haven't told the compiler how you want to do it.  It even suggest a solution: "(are you missing a cast?)"

There are 2 ways to do it:

1. Explicitly cast:

   string value = (string)expressionEv.Evaluate();
2. Call the ToString() method that all objects have (inherited from the base object class):

   string value = expressionEv.Evaluate().ToString();

I would suggest you use the ToString method.  The explicit cast runs a risk of throwing an exception if the type isn't ultimately a string.

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation `Evaluate` returns an `object`, so you need to explicitly cast it to a `string`.

```
string value = (string)expressionEv.Evaluate();
```

Or call `ToString()`:

```
string value = expressionEv.Evaluate().ToString();
```

Note that `Evaluate` can also throw an exception, so casting might fail.